# PIC Interrupt driven UART with circular buffer at high baud rate

Tags: interrupt, pic, circular-buffer, uart

I am trying to read from a sensor with PIC 18f4550 at baud rate=38400. With a FIFO Circular buffer, I am able to store data from the sensor to an array.

The sensor will respond to a request command and return a measurement of 15 bytes (**the same as the circular buffer I created**). I have to grab all **15 bytes** and put \r\n at the end to separate each measurement since there is no deliminator.

So I used two pointers, **inputpointer** and **outputpointer** to store bytes and transmit byte out. Because 18f4550 only has one hard UART, I use it to read data and send commands to sensor and at the same time use a software UART to output to a laptop via RS232.

I request a new measurement when the buffer is read and sent to serial port.

It works well but I just want to know if there is a better way to avoid FIFO overrun when the head pointer overruns tail pointer, ie when there is a lot of data getting buffered but they cannot get output in time.

Here is the code:  16MHZ  PIC 18f4550  mikroC compiler

```
char dataRx[15];
char unsigned inputpointer=0;
char unsigned outputpointer=0;
        // initialize pointers and buffer.
void main() {
      ADCON1=0x0F;  //turn analog off

      UART1_Init(115200);  //initialize hardware UART @baudrate=115200, the same setting for the sensor
      Soft_UART_Init(&PORTD,7,6,38400,0); //Initialize soft UART to commnuicate with a laptop
      Delay_ms(100); //let them stablize



      PIE1.RCIE = 1;                //enable interrupt source
      INTCON.PEIE = 1;
      INTCON.GIE = 1;


      UART1_Write(0x00);            //request a measurement.
      UART1_Write(0xE1);            //each request is 2 bytes

      while(1){

        Soft_UART_Write(dataRx[outputpointer]);  //output one byte from the buffer to laptop
        outputpointer++;                        //increment output pointer
        if(outputpointer==0x0F)                 //reset pointer if it's at the end of the array
        {
            outputpointer=0x00;
            Soft_UART_Write(0x0D);              //if it's at the end, that means the buffer is filled with exactly one measurement and it has been output to the laptop. So I can request another measurement.
            Soft_UART_Write(0x0A);              //add \r\n
            UART1_Write(0x00);                  //request another measurement
            UART1_Write(0xE1);
        }



}
void interrupt(void){ //interrupt routine when a byte arrives
      dataRx[inputpointer]=UART1_Read();            //put a byte to a buffer
      inputpointer++;
      if (inputpointer==0x0F){inputpointer=0;}      //reset pointer.
```

}

Comment: FIFO Overrun? You have a FIFO underrun bug in your code: You don't check whether there is actually data in before sending the first byte. It probably only sort of works because you soft uart is slow.

Comment: @TurboJ I am getting dsPIC30f4011 with 2 UART modules and it's on the way. But I don't think it solves the problem. There are more codes for sending data then receiving data and receiving has high priority(interrupt driven) so eventually there will be an overrun unless I stop requesting until all bytes have been sent out.

Comment: is there any reason why not to use separate buffers for transmit and receive? technically they should be separate buffers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could DISABLE the interrupt WHILE you are transferring the sensor reading OUT and then RE-ENABLE it after completion of transferring the data out?

It may not make a significant difference but it may stop the FIFO overrun you mentioned?

Comment: I thought about that but what if there is a byte coming in after I disabled the interrupt but when I am still inside of the interrupt routine? I will lose that byte right?

Comment: Yes off course, you would lose the byte. And my apologies, I had thought your code blocks were the OTHER way round, where in the INTERRUPT you export the buffer data  to your laptop (every so often (timed or when buffer is full)) and in your MAIN loop you buffer the sensor readings.